# Voice Command API for Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I just got a new smart device that runs a custom Android build without Google APIs, the PlayStore, etc.

My app that I'm developing for this device should feature voice commands as an input method.

Since I cannot use `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`, I am looking for an alternative SDK.
This solution should preferably not launch a new Intent, but rather work inside my activity.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the few possibilities that you have is http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Perfect! Compiling the sample app took like 2 minutes. This seems to be just what I need!